# does data bricks delta table maintains column addition or deletion versions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I have a use case where the table columns will be changing [addition/deletion] at each refresh [currently its weekly refresh]. It is stored as delta format. is there any way that can we trach the version of these column addition/deletion like a kind of meta store.

Is there any where I can find such information in delta table or delta file format ?

Comment: how do you write the data? using the `.mode("overwrite")` ?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, Actually I'm using .mode("append"). it is transactional data.

Comment: you mean that you're changing the data? I don't understand the question completely

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, Im basically using databricks delta format for one of my table where it is transactional data, so i need to append on weekly basis but one cache here is that the number of columns that we receive for every week is purely dynamic [20% of columns].

If i could able to get the versions history from delta table where I can find since when the column is ingested and available in delta table, that would be more helpful for me to write dynamic query based on the version